# Higher-dimensional metrics in (hyper)-spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, metric-tensor

I want to compute the components of the Riemann curvature tensor (for a case similar to the Schwarzschild solution) in 4 + 1 dimensions, but I want to use a higher-dimensional analogue of spherical coordinates. I first want to investigate a metric for the Euclidean case, i.e. "flat" space-time with no matter or energy present. How would I write this Euclidean metric using a higher-dimensional analogue of spherical coordinates?

Comment: This link might help: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: Thanks. I had already found that page, but I've been looking for a confirmation of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Coordinate_systems_on_the_3-sphere also has some information, but, again, I've been looking for a non-Wikipedia source.

Comment: So, this?: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html
:-D . If you look around equation 12 he gives essentially the same coordinates as the wiki article, he just numbers them differently. Confirmation is given by equation 16. Then you just need to construct $dx^{1}$, $dx^{2}$, etc.

Comment: Thanks again. This is exactly what I need. The initial discussion is also helpful.

Comment: Hi HDE 226868. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic This was originally a conceptual question I asked myself; I think it's been answered. I don't think it's along the lines of homework, though. I have read the policy many times, though.

Comment: @Qmechanic Revisiting it, I think you were right. I'm adding the tag back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you basically asking to the formula of higher dimensional vectors to compute yourself being in the sphere at the center with appropriate lines to all vector points?

I think I get what your asking for I asked the same questions when I was younger

Anyways here's a [hyperlink to 6th dimensional operation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6260). The operator is used in quantum physics, but clearly they are talking about bosons and fermions. The reason I am referencing this is because this goes in the quantum level from one to six dimensions as far as the x y and the z but they use all this jargon now referencing your sphere of influence that you were talking about you could always plug in the sphere formula into the equation

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6260